Meaning of 神威如狱
I came across this as a chapter title - 神威如狱. When looking into it, it looks like it's part of a larger phrase, 神恩如海，神威如狱. I'm trying to determine how best to translate 神威如狱, it's clearly some sort of metaphor or idiom, but Google hasn't been too helpful. I saw that it's slang that online writers use, whereas the original was 神威如岳, but I just want to make sure that's true. If so, should it be 'God's Power is like a Mountain?'

The simplified version of 嶽(mountains) is not 狱 but 岳  (狱 means prison). Therefore, 狱 in 神威如狱 is a wrong character. The correct wording is: "神威如嶽/神威如岳"
神恩如海 = "God's grace is like (as vast as) oceans"
神威如岳 = "God's awesomeness is like (as enormous as) mountains"
The two phrases praise God's greatness (to a human, God is loving and stern at the same time)
If 狱 in 神威如狱 is not a typo, then it would mean "God's awesomeness is like (as depressing as) a prison" (humans are all prisoners under his awesome power). You have to read the chapter to determine if the author is a follower of God or a critic of God

Maybe 狱 pertains to 地狱 (hell) instead of 监狱 (prison)?

@Becky李蓓 The phrase was created by a contemporary web writer in one of his works. You need to read the book to find out what the writer meant.

According to Baidu, the phrases "神威如狱，神恩如海。" came from the web literature "弑魔". The linked web page provided a few reader's explanations of the phrases.  https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/16347799.html
"神威如岳" is the name of a web literature series. You might be able to dig out more information from here - https://www.qidian.com/book/1021115294/
